# Linear Algebra notation

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

What does this notation mean? Is it just dividing each element per colum with the respective column length. Something like dividing by norm() in Matlab.

[image: Notation which I do not understand]

Comment: Yes. If you think of each column as a vector, it turns each column into a unit vector by dividing by its length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dividing the vector (column) $v_j$ by its norm, which is $\langle v_j,v_j\rangle^{\frac12}$, that way each new vector $v_j'$ of your matrix has length 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's redefining the symbol like you suggested.  Something like `v = v + 1` in Matlab.  The new value of v is defined in terms of the old value, but then you ignore the old value going forward.